# Does adding another bed count as adding another guest on Booking.com?

Tags: accommodation, booking.com

I'm wondering if adding another bed counts as adding another guest?

I've booked a hotel for myself, but due to circumstances, another person will be joining me. Since the ticket is non-refundable I can't change the guest number.

I've talked to the hotel and said I'd like another bed, for an additional fee. (Which is reasonable.) But does this count as adding another guest? Since I won't be sharing two single beds by myself, would it be obvious that I'm having another guest?

I'd like to make sure, in case the hotel will just refuse entry.

Comment: Which country? In the US, you typically pay for the room, and they don't care how many people come (up to the given limit); in Europe, prices are often adjusted by person count.

Comment: Not sure of your concern.  You told the hotel you wanted another bed, they know abour your current booking, they gave you a price for the extra services.  Are you worried they will add more fees?

Comment: The only people who can answer this are the hotel. There may be no charge, a charge for a higher classification of room, and/or a charge for an additional guest. I'd email them and get whatever they say in writing if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard rules on hotels regarding extra bedding, I think 3-5 star hotels normally give extra bedding for free. I think hotel doesn't care that much if one or two guests will sleep on your room. Unless they're using the hotel amenities like pool, gym or having free breakfast then it will be a different scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**Generally yes.** You are adding another bed and there is fee for that which is normal but by doing so you are also saying that another person will be sleeping in the room at the same time.

That simply means there is another guest. Hotels normally add this info into their system for several reasons: Identifying who can access the hotel rooms, identifying if someone can use amenities and counting the person against the quota of maximum people in the building (usually due to local laws or safety regarding fire and evacuation).

Given how many countries and places with different laws there in the world, it is certain that this will be different in some place or another. The main point is that another bed implies another person and the hotel will act accordingly. In some places there is not even a charge for the additional bed and person but they will need to be declared and sometimes even registered with the police.